# Why we say decorators in TypeScript? Why not Annotation(like Java) or Attributes(like C#)?

Tags: typescript, annotations, attributes, decorator

I would like to know the reason why is this feature in TypeScript called `Decorator`?

Is it just a different name from `Annotation` or `Attribute`? Is there any other reason?

What is the difference between a `Decorator` and an `Annotation`/`Attribute`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because they do different things.

An annotation adds metadata to a piece of code that can later be read and used by other code. 
While a decoration decorates some code with some other code.

Take the case of logging.

A logging annotation can be retrieved at runtime by the logger (maybe via reflection) and logging will be generated according to it.

A logging decoration will surround the logged code with a function that logs information.

Answer (score 8):

Annotations in Java are **metadata** attached to class, methods etc.

However decorators in TypeScript are **functions** which can add metadata but can also add some **behavior** like logging.

More information: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md